# Always remember last compile-command?

Tags: compilation

How do I get Emacs to always remember the last compile-command? My compile-command (cc) in Emacs 24 settings is pure vanilla, no bells and whistles. I only changed the cc string itself ("python build.py"), and I sometimes type a different cc by hand and run it. But then Emacs tries to be helpful and remember a cc based on different buffers, it seems quite randomly. For example I change directory in dired and I get a compile command that is completely unrelated to what I am trying to do. Is there a way to disable compile-command helpfulness feature so it only remembers the last one? BTW, I usually get the last cc, but sometimes the feature freaks out.

Comment: I haven't used `M-x compile`. But doesn't `M-x compile` followed by `M-p` show you the last command you used there?

Comment: I can scroll through commands fine, using M-p, after M-x compile. My issue is I'd like M-x compile to always show me the last command. It usually does this, but sometimes it freaks out.

Comment: I use `compile` a lot,and never observed this (which might not be surprising since my setup is heavily customized as far as `compile` is concerned). Do you have reproducible steps that lead to the problem? Or is it completely random?

Comment: Also, I don't really understand what you mean by "remember a cc based on different buffers"? Which buffers are you talking about? You do have only one compilation buffer, right?

Comment: One compilation buffer yes, I am talking about the buffer I am on at the moment when I issue M-x compile. Emacs tries to come up with the "right" cc for that buffer.. or so it seems to me. I will try to replicate it, if I can.

Comment: Added `(add-to-list 'compile-history compile-command)`. Testing now..